# Incorrect file opening (ifstream) when unsetting a variable in C++

Tags: c++, runtime-error, ifstream

I have the following C++ program. I  open a file (inputmincut.txt) and read its content. 
Whenever I comment the n=0 line the program crashes. This makes no sense to me. What could be happening?

```
using namespace std;
ifstream input_file;
ofstream output_file;

int n;

  void read()
    {
     int current=0; 
     int pos=0; 
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      { 
       input_file>>current;
       input_file>>pos;      
       while(pos!=-1)
        input_file>>pos;                          
      }        

     }  


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    input_file.open("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\inputmincut.txt");
     input_file>>n;
     read();
     input_file.close();
     //n=0;
     input_file.open("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\inputmincut.txt");
     input_file>>n;
     read();
     input_file.close();


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the text input.

10
1  2  10 -1
2  3  1  -1
3  4  2  -1
4  5  3  -1
5  6  4  -1
6  7  5  -1
7  8  6  -1
8  9  7  -1
9  10  8 -1
10  1  9  -1

Comment: You're doing absolutely no error checking. That results in program that "don't work" and no one knows why. Pretty much all the lines that deal with I/O in your code should include error checking. Especially file open. And reading from the file.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would suggest changing your `read` function to take the file name as an arguement and not use globals. Side effect - if you use the streams inside `read`, `close` will be called automatically for you and you dont need to do it.

Comment: Don't use global variables plz.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_file.open("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\inputmincut.txt");
```

Are you sure that using `"\\"` instead of `"\"`to express a path in your OS!I think you should check your path of the file,and check whether do you open your file?

Comment: If you use single backslashes in literal strings, they get interpreted (escape sequence). Double-backslash is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check that the file is open for reading.
You can write something like this :

```
void ropen(std::string const & path, std::ifstream & file)
{
    file.open(path.c_str(), std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary);
    if(!file.is_open()) throw std::exception(
        path +
        std::string(": cannot open file for reading.")
    );
}
```

then :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::istream file;
  ropen(path,file);
  std::line;
  while(getline(file, line))
  {
    do something with your line
  }
  return 0;
}
```